# Why does Java let you cast to a collection?

Tags: java, collections, interface, casting

I have a simple `foo` class,  and I am able to cast to a collection interface (either `Map` or `List`) without any compiler error. 
Note that `Foo` class does not implement any interface or extends any other class.

```
public class Foo {

    public List<String> getCollectionCast() {
        return (List<String>) this;    // No compiler error
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCollection2Cast() {
        return (Map<String, String>) this;    // No compiler error
    }

    public Other getCast() {
        return (Other)this;     // Incompatible types. Cannot cast Foo to Other
    }

    public  static class Other {
        // Just for casting demo
    }

}
```

Why does the Java compiler not return **incompatible types error** when I try to cast the `Foo` class to a collection?

`Foo` does not implement `Collection`. I would expect an incompatible types error, because given the current `Foo` class signature, this cannot be a `Collection`.

Comment: You could write a subclass of `Foo` that implements `List` or `Map`.

Comment: @istovatis because `Other` is a class, and a subclass of `Foo` cannot also extend `Other`.

Comment: In the question above there are two classes that implement two interfaces. Here the foo class does not implement any interface. In addition, in the question you provided, compiler complains in an interface cast, but not complaints in the other. Hence, we have to do with two different examples

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It's not because they're collection classes, it's because they're *interfaces*. `Foo` doesn't implement them, but subclasses of it could. So it's not a compile-time error, since those methods may be valid for subclasses. At *runtime*, if `this` isn't of a class that implements those interfaces, naturally it's a runtime error.

If you change `List<String>` to `ArrayList<String>`, you'll get a compiler-time error for that, too, since a `Foo` subclass could implement `List`, but can't extend `ArrayList` (since `Foo` doesn't). Similarly, if you make `Foo` `final`, the compiler will give you an error for your interface casts because it knows they can never be true (since `Foo` can't have subclasses, and doesn't implement those interfaces).

Answer (score 47):

The compiler doesn't prevent code from casting a type to an interface, unless it can establish for sure that the relationship is impossible.

If the target type is an interface, then it makes sense because a class extending `Foo` can implement `Map<String, String>`. However, note that this only works as **`Foo` is not `final`**. If you declared your class with `final class Foo`, that cast would not work.

If the target type is a class, then in this case it would simply fail (try `(HashMap<String, String>) this`), because the compiler knows for certain that the relationship between `Foo` and `HashMap` is impossible.

For reference, these rules are described in [JLS-5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) (T = target type - `Map<String, String>`, S = source type - `Foo`)

> **If T [target type] is an interface type:**
>
> - If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>     
>    ***Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might).***
> - If S is a final class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.

Note the ***bold-italic*** comment in the quoted text.

Answer (score -6):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

> All Superinterfaces:
>       Collection, Iterable

Foo is a List is a Collection.

Comment: No, `Foo` is neither a `List` nor a `Collection`