# Casting an unimplemented interface to an object

Tags: java, casting

I have a class with the same methods implemented as the interface

```
public class MyClass {

String getString(final String stringName) {
//doSomething
    };
}
```

This is the interface definition -

```
public interface MyInterface {

String getString(final String stringName);
}
```

Is it possible to cast the interface to the class object-

```
MyInterface interace = new MyInterface;
MyClass class = (Myclass) interface;
```

Comment: why don't you check and see for yourself?

Comment: Check [this question: Why does Java let you cast to a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698154/why-does-java-let-you-cast-to-a-collection/) and the one it's a duplicate of.

Comment: Did you mean "cast the class to the interface"? That unfortunately does not work (no duck typing in Java), but is a reasonable wish. The other way around does not make much sense, as the class could have more method and fields that the interface does.

Comment: You can't even write the first line of this. If the interface has no implementations, you can't in practice use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to cast the unimplemented class object to the interface type as you would get an `ClassCastException` at runtime. This is because Java does not support [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), it doesn't check whether the method signatures are the same or not.

But you can use java-8 **method reference** to pass the logic you implemented in the `MyClass` `getString` to the interface reference type:

```
class MyClass {
    String getString(final String stringName) {
        return stringName;
    }
}
interface MyInterface {
    String getString(final String stringName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //MyInterface  myInterface = (MyInterface)new MyClass(); //java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyClass cannot be cast to class MyInterface
    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
    MyInterface  myInterface = clazz::getString;
    System.out.println(myInterface.getString("test"));
}
```

Also you cannot instantiate a interface as you have done in your code.

Comment: And if the interface has more than one method, you could generate a proxy that delegates all of them. (But of course, if you control `MyClass` you should just adjust it to implement the interface directly).